# Calculate sum of object's attribute in List of List (with stream)

Tags: java, list, java-8

I'm using Java 8, and I want to resolve my problem using `List.stream()` functionnalities.

Here's my problem :

This is the `Score` class (`Player` class does not matter) :

```java
public class Score {

    private Player player;
    private int score;

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

At the start of my program, I have a list of players populated :

```
List<Player> players; // Populated elsewhere
```

My program then does what it has to do, and I get a variable of this type :

```
List<List<Score>> scores; // Populated elsewhere
```

Now i want to print a formatted output such as this for each players :

```
Player.getName() + " : " + averagedScore;
```

where `averagedScore` is the sum of the `score.getScore()` value for one `Player` divided by the number of occurences of a Score for this Player in my `scores` variables.

---

Now, what I've done so far :

```
for (Players player : players) {
    scores.stream().filter(x -> x.stream().anyMatch(y -> y.getPlayer().equals(player)));
}
```

But I don't see how to calculate the sum of `element.getScore()` contained in sublists and filtered by `element.getPlayer()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a combination of the `groupingBy` and `averagingInt` collectors after having "flatMapped" your list of lists:

```
Map<Player, Double> scoreByPlayer = scores.stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(groupingBy(Score::getPlayer, averagingInt(Score::getScore)));

scoreByPlayer.forEach((p, s) -> System.out.println(p + " : " + s));
```

<sub>Note: requires the following static imports:</sub>

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.averagingInt;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```

---

For reference, full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Player adam = new Player("Adam");
  Player pat = new Player("Pat");
  Player susie = new Player("Susie");
  List<List<Score>> scores = new ArrayList<> ();
  scores.add(Arrays.asList(s(adam, 1), s(pat, 2), s(susie, 3)));
  scores.add(Arrays.asList(s(adam, 2), s(pat, 4), s(susie, 6)));
  scores.add(Arrays.asList(s(adam, 3), s(pat, 6), s(susie, 9)));

  Map<Player, Double> scoreByPlayer = scores.stream()
                  .flatMap(List::stream)
                  .collect(groupingBy(Score::getPlayer, averagingInt(Score::getScore)));

  scoreByPlayer.forEach((p, s) -> System.out.println(p + " : " + s));
}

private static Score s(Player p, int score) { return new Score(p, score); }

public static class Score {
  private final Player player;
  private final int score;
  public Score(Player player, int score) {
    this.player = player;
    this.score = score;
  }

  public Player getPlayer() { return player; }
  public int getScore() { return score; }
}

public static class Player {
  private final String name;
  public Player(String name) { this.name = name; }
  @Override public String toString() { return name; }
}
```